# jquery: trigger element methods, which are only in the parent elem

Tags: jquery

whether it is possible to do so?

```
<div id="search">
<div id="elem"></div>
</div>

<div id="search2">
<div id="elem"></div>
</div>
```

------this is example what i`m trying to do--------

```
$('#search').ready(function(){//i want to declare parent elem
    $('#elem').html('some');//make all actions what inside that parent elem
});
$('#search2').ready(function(){//i want to declare parent elem2
    $('#elem').html('some2');//make all actions what inside that parent elem
});


//or is it possible only like that:
$('#search #elem').html('some');
$('#search2 #elem').html('some2');
```

Comment: There is no element ready, What is the use case? Are these elements added later on to DOM? if not just place your last piece under `document.ready`.

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page, your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the basics: first of all, you shouldn't have duplicate `id`s, [the `id` attribute **should be unique**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), and hence you shouldn't have this problem of identifying which target you are referring to.

Secondly, there is no such thing in jQuery as `$(element).ready()`, the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method is fired when the DOM in its entirety is fully loaded and ready to be manipulated.

Thirdly, as for your question, you can narrow down the selectors to make sure you are targeting the children of a specific element using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), as such:

#### HTML

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="elem"></div>
</div>

<div id="search2">
    <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#search').on('click', function(){
          $(this).find('.elem').html('some');
     });

     $('#search2').on('click', function(){
          $(this).find('.elem').html('some2');
     });
 });
```

Comment: my example is only example to catch the idea what i`m trying to do
-----------
I WANT TO REPLACE 
$('#search #elem').html('some');
$('#search #elem2').html('some');
$('#search #elem3').html('some');

TO

$('#search').ready(function(){

 $('#elem').html('some');
 $('#elem2').html('some');
 $('#elem3').html('some');
});

-----------
is it possible that it will not change both #elem value ?

Comment: As I and @PSL told you, there is no such things as `$(element).ready()`. If you would describe your use case exactly, perhaps with a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) or another example perhaps we could help you.

Comment: did u understand my idea ?
if u want to go children elem then u need
$('main-elem child-elem')
is it possible to do like that
$('main-elem').some_jquery_function(
$('child-elem').click();
$('child-elem2').focus();
);